# How to display something depending on the number of posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

Need help with writing conditional for my WordPress site (cant find similar thread). Don't know if it can be done with WordPress conditional tags.

What I want to accomplish:

If currently logged user published 0 posts show something (for example link number one) else if user published more than 0 posts show something else (link number two).

I managed to write myself simple if statements for displaying menus depending on user role but i cannot find solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a count_user_posts() function:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the database using the [mysqli_connect](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) PHP function, then taking into account the [schema of wordpress databases](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) we have to make the other steps as follows.

The [get_current_user_id()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id) wordpress function returns the id of the user who is currently logged in. Then you can use this value like this:

```
$query = "select count(*) from wp_posts where post_author = ".get_current_user_id();
```

and finally, you have to run the query as described in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Answer (score 0):

It was really quite simple (thank you jonahs).

```
<?php

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $user_ID );

if ( $user_post_count == 0 ) {
echo 'message one';
} else {
echo 'message two';
}
?>
```